# How to solve Maven dependency on rt.jar for OS X?

Tags: java, macos, maven-2

I have the following dependency in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
   <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

My problem is I'm trying to build on a Mac (10.6.4) which doesn't have an rt.jar.

Is there a different system path I should be using for doing a build on OS X?  Is there a clean way to specify this in my pom.xml with out breaking the pom for developers using windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to this jar is `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bundle/Classes/classes.jar`. But as this dependency is basically a dependency to the JRE, you don't really need it.

Comment: Thanks that worked.   The only thing I'd add is after a bit of searching I figured out how to make the dependency change based off of the OS by using "profiles" in Maven (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).